# Estimate number of balls by picking a random bin

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, estimation, sampling, balls-in-bins

This is a tweak to the standard balls and bins problem where we (usually) come up with bounds on the max load or empty bins. I am interested in estimating $M$ when $M$ balls are (uniformly) thrown into $N$ bins by randomly picking one bin and seeing the number of balls in it. How many bins do I need to query to get a good estimate? Intuitively, it seems like seeing one bin should be enough to estimate $M$ upto constant factors (or $\log M$ factors).

Edit: For e.g., let us say that $M = \Omega(N\log N)$.

Edit 2 (see comments): I guess, my only doubt is whether the error (or $\delta$) we choose in Chernoff bounds directly corresponds to the error in the estimate, or not. Suppose fix a $\delta$ for both sides of deviation, then does the estimate also have the same error on both sides (with the same high probability that we get due to Chernoff bounds).

Comment: @saulspatz So the idea is to get an estimate with a high probability; of course, that estimate might be wrong in some cases! I have edited the question.

Comment: If we find that the bin has $d$ balls in it, don't you think that the estimate should be something like $dN$? Intuitively, by Chernoff bounds arguments, we can say something like the max and min do not deviate from the mean too much (for _any_ bin by union bounds); mean here is $d = M/N$.

Comment: I guess, to answer your question, if $d = 0$, then the estimate is also 0 (with very low probability).

Comment: Yes, I must have my head on upside down.  Sorry.

Comment: Ah it's okay! I get confused with trivial calculations all the time too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ be the number of balls in each bin. Suppose you look at $K$ bins; by symmetry, let's say they're the first $k$. Note that $Y:=\sum_{i=1}^K X_i\sim Bin(M,K/N)$. The expected value of $Y$ is $MK/N$, and is the sum of $M$ $\{0,1\}$ random variables, hence by standard Chernoff bounds, for any $0\leq \delta\leq 1$,
\begin{align}
\Pr(Y\not\in [(1-\delta)MK/N,(1+\delta)MK/N])&=\Pr(NY/K\not\in [(1-\delta)M,(1+\delta)M])\\
&\leq 2\exp(-\delta^2 KM/3N)\\
&\leq 2\exp(-\Omega(1)\delta^2 K\log N)\\
&\leq \frac{2}{N^{\Omega(1)\delta^2K}}.
\end{align}

If you want an estimate multiplicatively within a $\delta$ factor with probability at least $1-\epsilon$, you evidently need to query only $O(\log(1/\epsilon)/\delta^2\log N)$ of the buckets and form the naive estimator. In particular, for fixed $\delta$ and $\epsilon$, you can get away with looking at a single bin for $N$ large enough (assuming $M=\Omega(N\log N)$).

Comment: In the usual Chernoff arguments for balls and bins, we argue for a particular bin first and then apply union bounds to say something about all the bins; for e.g., $Z_{ij}$ refers to the ball $i$ being thrown to bin $j$, and $Y_j = \sum_i Z_{ij}$. Now, these $Z_{ij}$ are independent for a fixed bin $j$.

Are $X_i$'s in your answer (mutually) independent Bernoulli random variables? Also, $Y \sim Bin(M,K/N)$ might be wrong? I agree that $E[Y] = MK/N$ by linearity of expectation.

Comment: The $X_i$ are negatively associated. However, if I look at just the first $K$ bins and ask how many balls landed in any of those bins, this is a sum of $M$ independent $0/1$ random variables, each of which has probability $K/N$ of landing in those $K$.